# Python subprocess: capture output of ffmpeg and run regular expression against it

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, ffmpeg, stderr

I have the following code

```
import subprocess
import re
from itertools import *

command = ['ffprobe', '-i', '/media/some_file.mp4']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
text = p.stderr.read()
retcode = p.wait()
text = text.decode('utf-8')
p = re.compile("Duration(.*)")

num = 0 #for debugging
for line in iter(text.splitlines()):
    print(str(num) + line) #for debugging
    m = p.match(str(line))
    if m != None:
        print(m.group(1))
```

When I look at the output there is a line that says "Duration" on it, however it is not captured, print(m.group(1)) is never reached. If I change the text variable to a hardcoded string of "Duration blahblah" I get " blahblah", which is what I expect. It seems like the regex doesn't recognize the text coming back from stderr. How can I get the text into a format that the regex will recognize and match on?

---

I have come up with the following solution, should it help anyone else attempting to capture duration from ffmpeg using python

```
import subprocess
import re

command = ['ffprobe', '-i', '/media/some_file.mp4']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
text = p.stderr.read()
retcode = p.wait()
text = text.decode('utf-8')
p = re.compile(".*Duration:\s([0-9:\.]*),", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
m = p.match(text)
print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = re.compile(r".*?Duration(.*)")
```

Try this.`match` starts from the begining while there may might be something before `duration`.

Comment: It should be fine to use greedy here instead.

Comment: @JesseAdam if you can post `stderr` here it would be easier to debug